# Excel fórmula tendencia

Tags: excel

quiero averiguar que pasos hace excel para calcular la tendencia, es decir, me gustaría saber que hace la funcion TENDENCIA del excel.

Tengo una tabla con las ventas de los 5 últimos años (2015-2019) y quisiera saber la tendencia para el 2020, pero quiero calcularla yo, no quiero usar la funcion tendencia.

alguna pista?
Gracias

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que StackOverflow es un sitio que ayuda a programadores en sus desarrollos, creo que este no es el sitio adecuado donde hacer esta pregunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Según la página de Office:

> La función tendencia devuelve valores en una tendencia lineal. Se
>   ajusta a una línea recta (usando el método de los mínimos cuadrados) a
>   los argumentos conocido_y y conocido_x de la matriz. TENDENCIA
>   devuelve los valores y a lo largo de esa línea para la matriz de
>   nueva_matriz_x que especifique.

Es decir, que la función TENDENCIA el metodo de los "Mínimos Cuadrados" (explicación detallada en [esta página web](https://miprofe.com/minimos-cuadrados/)).

Por lo tanto según la explicación de la pagina citada:

-Tú tienes una serie de números que has apuntado (tus ventas).

-Tienes la fecha exacta de cada recaudación (en este caso pondremos de ejemplo que tienes apuntada la recaudación de 4 años, en vez de la recaudación mensual. Supongo que tendrás apuntada la recaudación mensual, en ese caso, tan solo tendrás que cambiar algunos de los siguientes valores).

Valores necesarios para la operación TENDENCIA:

- -n Es el número de muestras que tienes, en el caso de este ejemplo 4, porque tenemos 4 años.
- -Σx Es la suma de todas las x. Considerando que no nos va a importar el año en el que empecemos, sino cuantos años vamos a coger a partir de ese, podemos sustituir Σx en nuestra ecuación por lo siguiente: En nuestro caso concreto, como n = 4... Σx = 4+3+2+1 = 10
- -Σ(x*y) Es la suma de las multiplicaciones entre los meses y las ganancias, es decir:

Referencia

```
 X--------------Y-----------(x*y)
 Mes 1 -> 1000 € -> 1 * 1000 = 1000
 Mes 2 -> 750  € -> 2 * 750  = 1500
 Mes 3 -> 1200 € -> 3 * 1200 = 3600
 Mes 4 -> 1500 € -> 4 * 1500 = 6000
 Σ(x*y) = 1000 + 1500 + 3600 + 6000 = 12100
```

- -Σy Es la suma de TODAS las ganancias (En nuestro caso, 1000 + 750 + 1200 + 1500. Por lo que, para nosotros, Σy = 4450).
- Σx*x Es la suma de la multiplicación de todos los meses que tenemos anotados. Es decir, en nuestro caso, como n = 4 -> Σx*x = 4*4 + 3*3 + 2*2 + 1*1 -> En nuestro caso, Σx*x = 16 + 9 + 4 + 1 = 30
  [image: img1]

Finalmente, los últimos valores se llaman "Y" y "X". "Y" representa el dinero que vamos a esperar ganar en el año "X".

Si seguimos los pasos de la página o la ecuación de arriba, podremos llegar a nuestra conclusión:
En nuestro caso, con los datos que he mencionado antes, podemos operar de esta manera:

```
Y = ((( (4 * 12100) - (10 * 4450) ) / ( (4 * 30) - (10 * 10) )) * X) + (( (4450 * 30) - (10 * 12100) ) / ( (4 * 30) - (10 * 10) )) = (195 * x) + 625
```

Por lo tanto, si queremos saber las ganancias del año nº X, tendremos que operar (en nuestro caso) 625 + (195 * X).

En el caso de la operación para el año 2020, tendríamos que saber que el último año en el que cogimos datos fue 2019, por lo que 2020 - 2019 = 1 -> X = n+1 -> X = 4+1 = 5

Con el dato de que X para 2020 es igual a 5, podríamos terminar la operación, teniendo que "Y" = 625 + (5 * 195) = 1600

Comment: Muchas Gracias Clipi... No me dió por mirar en la página de office.
he realizado la prueba y el resultado ha salido clavado..